# Using proxyquire to stub require in 3rd party modules dependency

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, proxyquire

I am trying to use proxyquire to stub a require in a module that is required by a 3rd party module.

Example:

My module requires a 3rd mod called 'foo'.

That module depends on another library called 'bar' and in bar there is a require I want to mock.  Is this possible?

in 3rd party lib called 'three':

```
  var bar = require('bar');
```

in bar lib:

```
  var thingiwanttomock = require('thingiwanttomock');
```

Then something like this in my test:

```
  it("test", function() {
    var mocked = proxyquire('thingiwanttomock', {});
  });
```

**EDIT:**

I think what I want is something like this:

```
var three = proxyquire('three', {
  'bar': {
    'thingiwanttomock': {
       'mocked': true 
     }
    }
  }
});
```

However if I put a console log in the bar library and print out what the thingiwanttomock variable is after the require, its not my mocked object.

in bar lib:

```
  var thingiwanttomock = require('thingiwanttomock');
  // this is not my object object
  console.log('thingiwanttomock should be a mock', thingiwanttomock);
```

Will proxyquire actually change what gets pulled in from a require statement in the dependent lib?  Maybe that is where my confusion lies.

Comment: What do you think about putting `var thingIwantToMock = require('thingiwanttomock');` in your test and than mock it from there?

Comment: The reason I am trying to avoid that is that I don't depend on thingiwanttomock so I cannot require it.  I don't want to add that dependency just to test.  I think this is something I can do with proxyquire.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am having the same issue and I do not want to put the 3rd party module in my test as Srle suggests.